# Cannot Get to Load Values on Form Load! VB SQL Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, subroutine

I am trying to get some values on form load, that will be automated as the user shall not type these in. I am doing these in the form of Subroutines so it looks neater and it is easier for me to reuse.
Bellow you can have a look at the 5 subs I have, the first one works perfectly and the rest dont! I dont get it because they are based on the same principle!

```vb
Sub CustomerNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used For Customer
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customer"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Customer")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Customer").Rows.Count
    Customer_IDTextBox.Text = Rows
End Sub
Sub OrderNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Order"
    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Order Table
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds.Tables(0))
    Rows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    NewOrderID.Text = Rows + 1
    Order_IDTextBox.Text = NewOrderID.Text

End Sub
Sub PizzaNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Pizza Table
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Pizza"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Pizza")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Pizza").Rows.Count
    NewPizzaID.Text = Rows + 1
    Pizza_IDTextBox.Text = NewPizzaID.Text

End Sub
Sub DrinksNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Drinks Table
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Drinks"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Drinks")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Drinks").Rows.Count
    NewDrinksID.Text = Rows + 1
    Drinks_IDTextBox.Text = NewDrinksID.Text

End Sub
Sub SidesNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Sides Table
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Sides"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Sides")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Sides").Rows.Count
    NewSidesID.Text = Rows + 1
    Sides_IDTextBox.Text = NewSidesID.Text

End Sub
```

And here is the bit that I call on form load for this to execute:

```
Private Sub frmProducts_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SetValues()

    CustomerNo()
    OrderNo()
    PizzaNo()
    DrinksNo()
    SidesNo()

End Sub
```

The set values sub works fine so that is not a problem, it is just setting the values at the beggining. It doesnt show an error or nothing, it is just that the code doesnt seem to work and it does nothing, apart from the first CustomerNo() bit.

Thanks again a lot in advance.

Regards,

Jose

Comment: a)defining a row ID from the row count is exceptionally bad.  Access will do this for you if the ID column is AutoNumber (meaning none of that code would be needed!) b) it is really really bad to put an ID in a text box where the user can CHANGE it; besides you can store it in a *variable* and not even bother the user with the ID c) `SetValues` must be doing something that the others are not.  Since none of the 5 work, maybe remove 4 of them and replace with the `SetValues` code.

Comment: have you stepped through the subroutines to see if the datatables are even being loaded correctly?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback. I have tried doing it by autonumber on access, but couldnt get it to work that way, and this way it did. I understand the risks of putting it though a textbox, but the textbox will not be visible for the user, I have set it as visible now for testing purposes. All I need to do is get this program working as a prototype, but needs to read and write to database.

Comment: SetValues has nothing to do with the tables, as it is just to set the values of text boxes for my running total bit (Different story which is working) the bit that I said that worked is CustomerNo() the rest are based on same principle but dont work? :/

Comment: set a breakpoint and step thru the code as it executes and see why. if the TBs are invisible, then just use a variable, much cleaner and less overhead than a UI control

Comment: I have and there are no errors or nothing, I dont know why it just doesnt work...And the reason why it is set as a text box is cause I just dragged and dropped it on the from from Data sources, but I am not really very good at coding and wouldnt know kind of like how to pass it on etc..

Comment: stepping thru code does not reveal errors, but logic errors aka bugs.  somewhere in that code something is not doing what you thought it would.  Step thru the code, watch each line execute to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors going on here: 1) the word "Order" is a reserved word in nearly any DB.  So you have to delimit it or the DB will throw an error.  2) in your datasets, you are trying to fill table(0) that you didn't create (and therefore, doesn't exist).  Try this code:

```
'It is always best to put settings like this in a private property.'  
'Better still, learn how to look it up from your project settings (file)'
Private ReadOnly Property ConnString As String
    Get
        return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    End Get
End Property

Sub OrderNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    conn.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [Order]"
    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Order Table'
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds)
    Rows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    NewOrderID.Text = Rows + 1
    Order_IDTextBox.Text = NewOrderID.Text
End Sub

Sub PizzaNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Pizza Table'
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Pizza"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Pizza")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Pizza").Rows.Count
    NewPizzaID.Text = Rows + 1
    Pizza_IDTextBox.Text = NewPizzaID.Text
End Sub

Sub DrinksNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Drinks Table'
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Drinks"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Drinks")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Drinks").Rows.Count
    NewDrinksID.Text = Rows + 1
    Drinks_IDTextBox.Text = NewDrinksID.Text
End Sub

Sub SidesNo()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer 'Used for Sides Table'
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Sides"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Sides")
    Rows = ds.Tables("Sides").Rows.Count
    NewSidesID.Text = Rows + 1
    Sides_IDTextBox.Text = NewSidesID.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: That is why! It was the word Order...Thanks a lot! Much Much Appreciated! And also, thanks for the connection string hint, it is much better and easier to change